# Changing the \ast of kpfonts

Tags: math-mode, symbols, unicode-math

When using the KP-Font (OTF version), the asterisk `\ast` looks like this:

[image]

which is beautiful. However, in my lecture note, I need it to represent a certain operation, which should look like this:

[image]

Is there some way to modify this symbol?

---

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\begin{document}

$G \ast H$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[range=\ast]
\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}[range={}]

\begin{document}

$G \ast H$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! May I ask what is the line with `[range={}]` for?

Comment: @Jinwen XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX would use the font metrics of the last declared font.